# Can someone provide an overview of how to embed Lua?

Tags: lua

I'm working on a device that must support different recipes when operating on a consumable. One inserts the consumable, a QR code is scanned, and depending on the code a recipe is applied.

I'm using a Cortex-M4F and an FPGA to control some motors and that code is written in C++ and is running on FreeRTOS. What I most want Lua for is to do things like handle if/then/else logic and looping etc. I'll also need to extend it to support my motors which I don't think will be difficult using the C API (though I've never done this for Lua). But I won't need most if any of the libraries.

eLua doesn't seem like the right thing. If I understand that project it's about creating a binary image for a board and then running an application on top of it written in Lua. I just want a single task to be able to load and run a script.

I can probably afford 100-200 kB of flash for Lua alone which I think is plenty. RAM is 256 kB.

If someone has done this I'd like to hear how it went.

Comment: Did this with luajit a while back.  The are recipes online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something similar, but on bare metal with only 64 kB RAM, which is enough to run the VM. In general, I would say that the more RAM you have, the better (not less than 64 KB). To save RAM, I've made the [GC](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-collectgarbage) more aggressive and reduced the default representation of numbers to 32 bits (`#define LUA_32BITS`). If necessary you can also exchange the functions for memory allocation (malloc, etc.).
The flash should be enough.
I would recommend using Lua 5.3 (Emergency GC, build in binary operators, ...).

Normally the [source code](http://www.lua.org/download.html) should build without problems. The only parts I had to change were IO operations (`stdio.h`) and functions from `time.h` but that depends on how your platform handles it.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I had no problems building 5.3.5 as a C library. I only had to define l_signalT which I chose to define as an unsigned 32-bit value. I included "lua.hpp" in my C++ main and added some simple code I lifted from some posting somewhere but it's crashing due to a null pointer. I'll post those details as another question. The process stack and heap appear to be OK.